# Multiple references on one line of bibliography in LyX 2.0 with revtex4-1

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, lyx, citing, revtex

The `documentclass revtex4-1` allows multiple citations to appear on the same line in the bibliography. This is accomplished by adding a star next to the citation key [1]:

```
\cite{bethe, *feynman, *bohr, einstein}
```

However, can we add stars next to citation keys in LyX's GUI without using ERT (evil red text)?

[1] http://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/revtex/auguide4-1.pdf